# Post code snippet on Google group via email

Tags: gmail, google-groups

I like to compose my posts in Gmail. It keeps the draft safe. Now I want to write a post for a Google group but I am not sure how to format code in my post such that it is rendered as code on Google group.

Any suggestions? I am writing my mail in plain-text mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Groups do not support any board tag. Therefore there exists no way to format a code snippet by adding tags. The best you can do is change the font, e.g. the first message of https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/EIlGr-VoIzA